# How to inherit two classes in a third class when the first two are in base-child class relationship already?

Tags: java, immutability, delegation

Say I want to inherit Class A and Class B to Class C, (here B extends A as well). I am very well aware that though I can never do it directly in Java, but by using Mixin inheritance (Link: [http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html )](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html), that is use of one interface and other one as base class and internally using delegation I can do it, when A & B are unrelated class.

*How do I do the same when A & B have parent child them selves, and I need to inherit both of them in C?*

Just for your info, I am trying to do the same to achieve immutability in classes A & B.

Comment: Wait, what?  I'm not sure if you're saying `A extends B`, or if `A extends D` and `B extends E`.  In any event, you _cannot_ extend more than one class -- you can only extend one class and multiple interfaces.

Comment: @Louis Thanks but as I said before also that I very well know that I cannot extend more than one class. But what are the programming workarounds for this (if any?) if I absolutely have to do it.

Comment: There aren't really any.  You might be able to make `C` have `A` and `B` _fields_, switching the relationship from "is-a" to "has-a," but other than that?  There's basically nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If your `class B` already extends `class A`, then having `class C` extend `class B` would already do the trick. by extending `class B` you also get all functionality from `class A` that has not been specifically overridden in `class B`

Presumably you'd end up with:

```
class A
{
    public string hello()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
}

class C extends B
{
}

C foo = new C();
foo->hello(); // "Hello World!" because it is defined in A
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Kris, though the logic you gave is a no-brainer but  you have to understand I am trying to make the CLASS A and CLASS B as immutable, your logic doesn't holds when I am trying to achieve immutability by not setting anything directly on A or B's data members.

Comment: in that case you need (immutable versions of) `A` and `B` to be created in `C`'s constructor and assigned to private fields in `C`, a lot of plumbing and never (in)directly exposing any references from public API in `C`. I don't know any other way than delegate all needing-to-be-exposed logic manually in Java. I don't believe anything similar to php's magic __get and __call exists in java.

Comment: yeah I guess that is what I should be doing for the immutability stuff, I don't see any other elegant way to do the same. Thanks Kris!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make Class A an abstract class and then extend that in B and C. Let your common methods sit in A as abstract (or may be defined) and you may then override them in the concrete classes.

Comment: yeah that's a good point, but the problem is I have an existing class A which is already being used for long time and and has multiple subclasses hence changing the same will impact lot of things. But, thanks anyways!